# What would stop jQuery from being defined?

Tags: jquery

Within my Wordpress site, I have installed the Maps Marker plugin but I cannot it get it load a map within my theme: http://www.glutenfreeireland.com/test-map

When opened directly there is no issue: http://www.glutenfreeireland.com/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker/leaflet-fullscreen.php?layer=1

I have disabled all plugins and get the same error. The plugin author tested the plugin on a basic version of the site using the same theme but couldn't replicate the error, the map worked for him.

In my browser console the only error relating to the plugin is: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

At the plugin authors' suggestion I added wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); to the functions.php file but this didn't work either.

I write very basic PHP and am unfamiliar with jQuery so I don't know where to start in trying to work out what it is within my site that is stopping jQuery from being defined.

Are there tools for examining code errors or conflicts (suitable for a noob) or can anyone suggest next steps to determine the issue?

Comment: you have included some script which used jQuery before the jQuery library is included in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page you are referencing jQuery before the jquery library is added to the page...

if you look at your page source... the lines `}).addTo(layermap_1);
})(jQuery);` is appearing before `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.glutenfreeireland.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>` which is adding the jQuery library

Place all code that is referencing jQuery after the jQuery library include, so move that entire script block to the bottom of the page(after including jQuery)

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe this is the result of a plugin that moved scripts to the footer to speed up the site which I have long since removed. Unfortunately its' legacy was to leave its' changes behind. I am now trying to undo its' horrible-ness. Thanks again.